# How can I predefine amCharts periodSelector's maxDate and minDate?

Tags: amcharts

How can we predefine min and max date in amCharts stock charts.

Here example fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/TuLpK/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

min and max dates are defined by your data, there is no way to set it on period selector.